# How do i select data across two tables using SQL where a field from each table matches?

Tags: sql, oracle

Delphi 2010 & Oracle Database

I need to write a select statement across two tables

**Accounts & Master**

From the Accounts table, I need to select the `Account_Id, Account_Number, Bank_Id, and External_Code`

From the Master table, i need to select the `Account_String`.

The Master's Account_String field matches the Account's Extenal_Code field

thanx

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Sounds like a simple join, unless I'm missing something:

```
SELECT a.Account_Id, a.Account_Number, a.Bank_Id, a.External_Code, m.Account_String 
FROM Accounts a
INNER JOIN Master m ON m.Account_String = a.External_Code
```

Answer (score 2):

Standard SQL:

```
select Accounts.Account_id, Accounts.Account_Number, Accounts.Bank_Id,
    Accounts.External_Code, Master.Account_String  
from Accounts, Master
where Accounts.External_Code = Master.Account_String;
```

Note: You probably don't need both Accounts.External_Code and Master.Account_String in the result, as the query guarantees they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

You want an [inner join](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_%28SQL%29#Inner_join).

```
SELECT a.account_id, a.account_number, a.bank_Id, a.external_code, m.account_string
FROM accounts a JOIN master m ON a.external_code = m.account_string
WHERE ...;
```